# Not getting binary value in databricks

Tags: sql, apache-spark, binary, databricks

First i created a table in databricks with binary datatype

```
CREATE TABLE binary(binary_col BINARY);
```

The above query created a table in databricks now I inserted a value to it using query:

```
INSERT INTO binary VALUES (X'1');
```

It successfully uploaded into the table but when I viewed the table:

[image]

the 3rd row *AQ==* is added to the table instead of *01*.

Please let me know what is happening here, i think databricks converting it to base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will insert the binary value `1` into the `binary_col` column of the `binary` table.

```
INSERT INTO binary VALUES (CAST('1' AS BINARY))
```

For more info check [this](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/cast.html)

I also suggest using pySpark

```
# Import required libraries
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Establish a connection with Databricks using Databricks CLI
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('pandasToDatabricks').getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set('spark.databricks.service.server.enabled', 'true')
spark.conf.set('spark.databricks.service.token', '<DATABRICKS_ACCESS_TOKEN>')
spark.conf.set('spark.databricks.service.cluster.instanceProfile', '<AWS_INSTANCE_PROFILE>')

# Convert pandas dataframe to spark dataframe
pandas_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)

# Create table in Databricks workspace
dbutils.fs.rm('/mnt/<STORAGE_LOCATION>/table', True)
spark_df.write.format('parquet').mode('overwrite').save('/mnt/<STORAGE_LOCATION>/table')

# Insert data into table
spark.sql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table USING parquet LOCATION "/mnt/<STORAGE_LOCATION>/table"')
spark.sql('INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM table')
```

Comment: Not working it still show me in base64 format i think base64 is only way to show the binary data here and your cast converted into another base64 instead of  `AQ==`it converted to `MQ==` which is binary exactly ‘1’

Comment: Maybe it's the problem with your table viewer. DId you cross check get table data from CLI

Comment: I figured it out the databricks default binary(base64) so the data is visible in base64 and actually binay means base2 , actually they didnt mentioned any where they are using binary as base64 so i got confused, as far as data is not lost which format is no matter

Answer (score 1):

[image]

from this i concluded that the default it uses a base64 as binary